# post file to third party API using curl

Tags: php, curl

I am using below code to post a file to third party API -

```
$post = array('userName' => 'testabc','password'=>'testabc','FILE1'=>'abc.csv','cn'=>'10215');
        $fp = fopen("orders/abc.csv", 'r');

        $ch = curl_init("https://differentdomain.com/abc.cgi");

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "myuser:mypwd");            
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 86400); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, 'CURL_callback');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 128);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize("orders/abc.csv"));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        $suc = curl_exec ($ch);

        echo "==>".curl_error($ch);
        echo "-->".$suc; die;
```

It returns with 500 Internal Server Error. Not sure whether the way I am posting parameters are right or wrong.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You usually send a data string, not an array as the post fields.

Comment: are you sure this line is correct echo "-->".$suc; die; ????

Comment: yes.. but error occurs before printing the echo line.

Comment: It's a problem with the API. You have docs about this API?

Comment: yes, I have docs, but this API is trusted, so not sure, it's there problem or I made some mistake in code.

Answer (score 0):

[Upload image using curl](http://www.58bits.com/blog/2014/06/14/how-upload-file-using-php-curl)

Try this